# Keyboard control not working

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am currently trying to move a sprite using keyboard input.

Nothing looks wrong in my code :

```
function create(){
    cursors = Game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    /* ... */
}

function update(){
    var hitPlatform = Game.physics.arcade.collide(player, platforms);

    player.body.velocity.x = 0;
    if (cursors.left.isDown)
        player.body.velocity.x = -150;
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
        player.body.velocity.x = 150;
    if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down && hitPlatform)
        player.body.velocity.y = -350;
}
```

When I press cursor keys, nothing happens.
It seems that Phaser does not detect it when keys are down (`cursors.left.isDown` value does not change).

Comment: Is there no error when pressing any key in the browser console?

Comment: @Julián no, no error, and now I think that the problem comes from my browser.